# Got Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angular, xss, angular4-router

Angular App throwing Cannot match any routes error with XSS script in URL :

I am developing an application in Angular 4. When I am trying to write routes for a feature module, I am getting an error as Error: Cannot match any routes.

Here's the routes code I have used:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'test/:name', component: TestCompnent},
  {path: '**', component: TestCompnent}
];
```

Routing is working fine and going to the TestCompnent when the route is something like test/angular or test/some-course-name but when I try to inject some XSS script into the same route, such as

```
test/<script>alert('hello')</script>,
```

its throwing an error as

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''hello''
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''hello''

Comment: You shouldn't inject XSS script into the route

Comment: Even for a hacker user, becausse i've got a blanc screen with this fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

That is expected and wanted behavior, since XSS is a major vulnarability for most services.
Therefor the guys and girls over at Google did their best to disable them.
[Docs](https://angular.io/guide/security#xss)

Comment: Thanks for your response,
Therefore, is there any solution to redirect to home page or another page, because when i got this error i have just blanc screen so there is no indication about the state of the application even for a hacker user.

Comment: From my experience your wildcard path `{{path: '**', redirectTo: ''}}` should already do the trick. Maybe this is overwritten by the XSS blocking behaviour and should possibly be reported as a bug.